# Why the MissingNo glitch doesn't work on my Pokemon Blue virtual console (eShop 3DS)?

Tags: pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green

I have seen many videos of people on YouTube performing the MissingNo glitch on the virtual console Pokemon Red/Blue (e.g.

), but I can't seem to make it work. I am doing the exact same stuff the videos are doing. What am I missing..? I've surfed for 20 mins, no luck. I'm champion of the league.

These are my steps:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/38qb4gs4pf4n1s1/Video%2025-10-2016%2C%2000%2015%2051.mov?dl=0

Comment: What name are you using?

Comment: Without sound it's difficult to say for certain, but I think you might have left Cinnabar island for a second, when you surfed so close to the northern end of the coast. Try surfing only 3 or 4 steps up and down, instead of the full length.

Comment: ^this. The minute you enter open water, you're no longer on 'Cinnabar Island' but whatever the route is, meaning the grass tile data (where the missingNo glitch comes from) gets overwritten.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems like this glitch does not exist in the Italian version of the game; this could be why you are not managing to reproduce it:

> This glitch was fixed in the Spanish and Italian versions of Pokémon Red and Blue by making the shore tiles act as water tiles

[source](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Old_man_glitch)

Comment: Oh no! That's unfortunate.. :( Good catch though, thanks!!

Comment: Wow really? Interesting...

Comment: I'm Italian and I confirm this. I luckily had an English Blue cartridge years ago to try that glitch. But Mew glitch still works in the Italian version.

Comment: You can actually pull this off by doing the fly glitch and picking specific trainers before returning to the zone you started the glitch in.